# How to add a Lua library on VS

Tags: lua, require, love2d

So I am a beginner in programming and I decided to learn Lua. I am adding a library to Lua (push: require 'push') but I am getting this error when I am running it on LOVE2D. What should I do?

Error

```
main.lua:1: module 'push' not found:
no field package.preload['push']
no 'push' in LOVE game directories.
no file 'push' in LOVE paths.
no file './push.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/luajit-2.1.0-beta3/push.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/push.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/push/init.lua'
no file './push.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/push.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'


Traceback

[love "callbacks.lua"]:228: in function 'handler'
[C]: in function 'require'
main.lua:1: in main chunk
[C]: in function 'require'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
```

Comment: Did you add the library? Do you have `push.lua` next to `main.lua`?

Comment: I figured out that this was the problem. Thank you though.